# requestAnimationFrame vs settimeout 0 для анимации display:none

Tags: javascript, transition

Пытаюсь сделать анимационные переходы как во Vue.js для блока с `display:none`

То-есть сначала блоку добавляется `display`, на следующем кадре должна начаться анимация, после `transitionend` все классы удаляются.

Изначально планировал использовать для определения следующего кадра requestAnimationFrame, но он отказывается правильно работать. Блок плавно скрывается, но появляется резко. Так же заметил что иногда код отрабатывает как надо, блок появляется плавно.

**Кто знает в чем разница между requestAnimationFrame и setTimeout 0? И есть ли смысл использовать requestAnimationFrame для подобных целей?**

Пример с [requestAnimationFrame](http://jsfiddle.net/jpbkasn0/) (Работает не всегда корректно).

Пример рабочего кода с `setTimeout`

**HTML**

```
<button id=btn1>Нажми</button>
<div id="con1" style="display: none;">Контент</div>
```

**JS**

```
var btn = document.getElementById('btn1');
var con = document.getElementById('con1');

var show = false;

btn.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    if (!show) {
        con.classList.add('fade-enter');
        con.classList.add('fade-enter-active');
        con.style.display = "";

        setTimeout(function() {
            con.classList.remove('fade-enter');
            con.classList.add('fade-enter-to');
            con.addEventListener('transitionend', function n(e) {
                con.classList.remove('fade-enter-active');
                con.classList.remove('fade-enter-to');
                con.removeEventListener('transitionend', n);
            });
        }, 0)
    } else {
        con.classList.add('fade-leave');
        con.classList.add('fade-leave-active');

        setTimeout(function() {
            con.classList.remove('fade-leave');
            con.classList.add('fade-leave-to');

            con.addEventListener('transitionend', function n(e) {
                con.classList.remove('fade-leave-active');
                con.classList.remove('fade-leave-to');
                con.style.display = "none"
                con.removeEventListener('transitionend', n);
            });
        }, 0)
    }

    show = !show;
});
```

**CSS**

```
.fade-enter, .fade-leave-to {
  opacity: 0;
}

.fade-enter-active, .fade-leave-active {
  transition: opacity 1s;
}

#con1 {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: #ddd;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Проблема была в том что requestAnimationFrame не гарантирует вызова в следующем кадре.

[Paul Irish](https://medium.com/@paul_irish/requestanimationframe-scheduling-for-nerds-9c57f7438ef4)

> All rAF callbacks always run in the same or next frame of work
>   Any rAFs queued in your event handlers will be executed in the ​same frame​.
>   Any rAFs queued in a rAF will be executed in the next frame​. (Same for any queued within IntersectionObserver or ResizeObserver callbacks.)

Для правильного поведения нужно вызвать requestAnimationFrame в requestAnimationFrame

```
let raf = window.requestAnimationFrame;

let nextFrame = function(fn) {
    raf(function() {
        raf(fn);
    });
};
```